# Accessing variables different view controllers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties, uiviewcontroller

Ive been reading a lot of links on how to pass variables from SO on how to do this including this link.

[Accessing variables of another class in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754686/accessing-variables-of-another-class-in-xcode)

however, i have already imported the FirstViewController.h file in my SecondViewController.m file in my FirstViewController.h file I have a variable defined as
.h
@property (nonatomic,retain) int test; 
.m
@synthesized test;

and in view did load SecondViewController.h i try to do

FirstViewContoller.test=10;

but the variable is not recognized.

Would like if anyone could help please

Answer (score 3):

You can't set properties on classes. You can only set properties of objects, i. e. **instances** of a class. You have to write

```
FirstViewController *vc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
vc.test = 10;
// use then vc for whatever it should be used.
```

Oh, and by the way: this is not in any way related to Xcode.

Comment: I agree with your answer but I also worry that it can lead to another common problem where this `FirstViewController` is not the one in the window's controller hierarchy.  It would be nice to know whether the poster **already** has a `FirstViewController` instance active in the program.

Comment: @PhillipMills totally agreed. Although it seems that OP didn't quite get this whole 'objects-ivars-classes-whatevermessystuff' thing... (Yes, that's the consequence of diving right into the making of The Best iPhone App Ever without knowing a bit of C, OO theory, etc...)

Comment: @PhillipMill Well, i already set test to equal 10 in FirstViewController, i just want to be able to get that 10 and do X function in SecondViewController

Comment: The important questions (IMHO) are: **which** FirstViewController object did you set it in and **which** SecondViewController is doing x?  (If you don't get that there can be multiple FirstViewController objects, each with its own `test`, then we're back at classes vs. instances.)