# GET request using AFNetworking and saving response

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am doing a simple GET request with AFNetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://someapi.com/hello.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Once I have made the request I want to be able to access the `responseObject` from any other method in the class.

I want to be able to save the responseObject so I can do something like display the output in a tableview.

Comment: AFNetworking calls all the call back block in main queue. So, the problem is not due to AFNetworking being asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to creat object models that will be represented by JSON. When you get the response you would then parse the data into the models. The approach we use is to return the response to the requester through a completion block. You don't have to parse the JSON into strongly typed objects, but it really is helpful long term. It's probably a good idea to farm out the network request operations into a separate class (called a service) as well. This way you can instantiate a new service and get notified through a completion block that it is finished. For example your service's request signature could look like this:

```
typedef void(^HelloWorldCompletionHandler)(NSString *helloWorld, NSError *error);


- (void)requestHelloWorldData:(HelloWorldCompletionHandler)completionHandler;

// implementation
- (void)requestHelloWorldData:(HelloWorldCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager GET:@"http://someapi.com/hello.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    id JSONResponse = [operation responseObject];
    if (operation.error) {
        completionHandler(nil, error);
    } else {
        // parse the response to something
        id parserResult = [self parseJSONResponse:JSONResponse];
        completionHandler(parserResult, nil);
    }
 }];
```

This way you'll know when the network request is complete, and you can set the data you want on a property within your class. Then you could call tableView.reloadData in order to use the data in your table.

All that code would go into a service type class. I like to organize my services by responsibility. I don't know how many different data calls you make, but we have several for our project. If for instance you were making a weather app you could potentially organize by Current Conditions, Daily Forecasts, and Hourly Forecasts. I would make a service for each one of these requests. Say I created a CurrentConditionsService. The header would look something like this:

```
typedef void(^CurrentConditionsCompletionHandler)(CurrentConditions *currentConditions, NSError *error);

@interface CurrentConditionsService : NSObject

// locationKey is some unique identifier for a city
+ (instancetype)serviceWithLocationKey:(NSString *)locationKey;

- (void)retrieveCurrentConditionsWithCompletionHandler:(CurrentConditionsCompletionHandler)completionHandler;

@end
```

Then in my implementation file I would make the request and invoke the given completion handler like I demonstrated above. This pattern can be followed by many different services to the point where all your services could inherit from a base class that handles the request/response portions. Then your subclasses could override specific methods and handle/parse the data appropriately based on type.

If you go the route of parsing the JSON responses into model objects, all your parsers will need to conform to a protocol. This way in your super class it doesn't matter what the concrete implementation of your parser is. You supply the super class with a concrete implementation and all it knows how to do is invoke the parser and return the response.

An example JSON parser protocol would look like this:

```
@protocol AWDataParser <NSObject>

@required
- (id)parseFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
- (NSArray *)parseFromArray:(NSArray *)array;

@end
```

And invoking it in your services super class:

```
- (id)parseJSONResponse:(id)JSONResponse error:(NSError **)error {

    NSAssert(self.expectedJSONResponseClass != nil, @"parseResponse: expectedJSONResponseClass cannot be nil");
    NSAssert(self.parser != nil, @"parseResponse: parser cannot be nil");

    id parserResult = nil;
    if (![JSONResponse isKindOfClass:self.expectedJSONResponseClass]) {
        //handle invalid JSON reponse object
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkServiceErrorDomain code:kNetworkServiceErrorParsingFailure userInfo:@{@"Invalid JSON type": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"expected: %@, is: %@",self.expectedJSONResponseClass,  [JSONResponse class]]}];
        }
    } else {
        if (self.expectedJSONResponseClass == [NSArray class]) {
            parserResult = [self.parser parseFromArray:JSONResponse];
        }else {
            parserResult = [self.parser parseFromDictionary:JSONResponse];
        }
        if (!parserResult) {
            if (error) {
                *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkServiceErrorDomain code:kNetworkServiceErrorParsingFailure userInfo:nil];
            }
        }
    }

    return parserResult;
}
```

Comment: This seems interesting, where does the code above go? Have you got any more example of this type of method?

Comment: I've updated the answer for you to include a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:

```
NSURL *COMBINAT = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://someapi.com/hello.json"];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        COMBINAT];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(savedata:)   withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
```

then simply call:

```
- (void)savedata:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSLog(@"Answer from server %@", responseData);
    // ... your code to use responseData
}
```

Comment: #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1

Comment: This returns a ton of numbers from the server, for example: Answer from server <7b225553 44223a22 556e6974 65642053 74617465 7320646f 6c6c6172 222c224a 5059223a 224a6170 616e6573 65205965 6e222c22

Comment: This is ok, you need to serialize data in  json format (don't froget to add JSONKit and #import "JSONKit.h")   NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
JSONObjectWithData:responseData           options:kNilOptions
     error:&error];
 //get value for a key in json 
 // NSString *REZULTATMEMO =[json objectForKey:@"idmemo"];
 //evaluate this
 if (![REZULTATMEMO isEqualToString:@"-1"] && [raspunsMEMO isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
  NSLog(@"good data %@", REZULTATMEMO);

Comment: Brilliant! If you update the answer with how to serialise the data I will mark as answered.

Comment: Final question, if I save the NSDictionary as a @property is it possible to call this in any other methods? for example not having to decale a void.

Comment: Updated answer. You just convert responseData to NSDictionary, then use any keys you need to evaluate. Keep in mind to check if responseData is not null :if(responseData ) {
   NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
          JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
          options:kNilOptions
          error:&error];

Comment: It is possible, read already answered question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754686/accessing-variables-of-another-class-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Just create a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) id savedResponseObject;
```

and set it in the success handler of the request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager GET:@"http://someapi.com/hello.json" 
  parameters:nil 
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    self.savedResponseObject = responseObject;
} 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Then you will be able to access it from other places in your class by referencing:

```
self.savedResponseObject
```

Comment: What exactly return null?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.savedResponseObject); The request is called before the property has been initialized